# Zoomable View in Android?

Tags: android

I want to build an Image based application like "Maps for Android". My application have an Activity display a big image[ImageView]. I want put "Pins"[Like custom overlay in Map] on this "big image". I want zoom in, zoom out, double tap zoom in, zoom out an scroll this Activity.

I found an example, an image zoom-able view:
http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

But it doesn't zoom view, it's just redraw a part of image.

Anybody have an idea?