# How to create a zoomable activity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, zooming, gestures

Basically, I just need my activity to feely zoom with the standard gestures: spread to zoom in, pinch to zoom out, and double tap to zoom in and double tap again to zoom back out

So far all my activities only fit to scale. My activity for the zoomable page will simply have an ImageView.

I tried looking for answers but could find a consistent one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple zoom for a `View`

```
 View view =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null); // get reference to root activity view
        setContentView(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            float zoomFactor = 2f;
            boolean zoomedOut = false;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(zoomedOut) {
                    v.setScaleX(1);
                    v.setScaleY(1);
                    zoomedOut = false;
                }
                else {
                    v.setScaleX(zoomFactor);
                    v.setScaleY(zoomFactor);
                    zoomedOut = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

But for more information take a look these links :

[Zoomable View in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951029/zoomable-view-in-android)

[Android Pinch and Zoom Image in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210443/android-pinch-and-zoom-image-in-activity)

http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html